# Dockerfile: Reverse Volume Declaration

Tags: linux, docker, containers, dockerfile, volume

I am building an image based on another image from the official docker hub. In image, there is a volume declared:

`VOLUME ["/var/lib/arangodb3", "/var/lib/arangodb3-apps"]`

However, I do not want the volume in my image. Is there any possibility, to revoke this volume command in my Dockerfile?

Comment: If the volume is already in the image built then you cannot reverse the volume link.

Comment: so there is nothing, you can do to create an image based on a database image that contains some data?

Comment: @jww why should this question be off-topic? There are almost 70,000 Docker-related questions on Stackoverflow and of course it is about programming/development since is use docker to run my database and application...